# SQL Query Join 4 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am New In SQL I want to write query to get a Report.

- **Employee** (EmployeeID,EmployeeName)
- **Job**(EmployeeID(Foreign Key),JobEndDate(Nullable))
- **Files** (FileID,FileName)
- **EmployeeFilling** (EmployeeID(Foreign Key), FileID(Foreign Key),ReceivingDate(Nullable), ExpiryDate(Nullable),ReturnedDate(Nullable), DeliveryDate(Nullable))

What I Want :

```
Sellect Filles where DeliveryDate Is Null & JobEndDate Is Not Null For All Employees
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for sharing your requirements. What have you tried? Have you heard about [joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What is "for all employees" support to mean?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT F.FileName FROM FILES F 
JOIN EMPLOYEEFILING EMPF ON F.FILEID = EMPF.FILEID 
JOIN JOB J ON J.EMPLOYEEID = EMP.EMPLOYEEID 
WHERE EMPF.DELIVERYDATE IS NULL AND J.JOBENDDATE IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do more research on the SQL joins and in which scenario it can be used.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/joining-three-tables-sql/

Please try below query for your questions.

```
SELECT employee.EmployeeID,employee.EmployeeName, Job.JobEndDate, Files.FileName,EmployeeFilling.DeliveryDate
FROM Employee e,Job j, Files f,EmployeeFilling ef
where e.EmployeeID =j.EmployeeID and e.EmployeeID = ef.EmployeeID and f.FileID=ef.FileID
and ef.DeliveryDate is null and JobEndDate is not null;
```